# Django ModelForm: Exclude a field which is not in Model

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am having hard time debugging this. I want to exclude `confirm_password` of `RegModelForm` in an extended `modelform` `UpdateRegModelForm`. I have tried to use `exclude` in the Meta class of `UpdateRegModelForm` but it seems to show `confirm_password` while rendering `UpdateRegModelForm` anyways. Not sure how to move forward.

```
class RegModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    org_admin_email = forms.CharField(
        label='If you know who should be the Admin, please add their email address below.'
              ' We\'ll send them an email inviting them to join the platform as the organization admin.',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs=({'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    )
    organization_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        label='Organization Name',
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Organization Name'}
        )
    )

    confirm_password = forms.CharField(
        label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ExtendedProfile

        fields = (
            'confirm_password', 'first_name', 'last_name',
            'organization_name', 'is_currently_employed', 'is_poc', 'org_admin_email',
        )

        labels = {
            'is_currently_employed': "Check here if you're currently not employed.",
            'is_poc': 'Are you the Admin of your organization?'
        }

        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'is_poc': forms.RadioSelect()
        }


class UpdateRegModelForm(RegModelForm):
    class Meta(RegModelForm.Meta):
        exclude = ('confirm_password',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fields` and `exclude` attributes are only relevant for fields that are created from the model. Since you've specified `confirm_password` directly in the form itself, that will always be present.

The way to remove it is to delete it from the `fields` dictionary of the form. You can do this in the `__init__` method:

```
class UpdateRegModelForm(RegModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateRegModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.pop('confirm_password')
```

You don't need to define Meta in this subclass at all.